# Most pythonic way to structure a file with different sets of data that are all based on one template

Tags: python, python-3.x

*** This is my first question on Stackoverflow, I hope I'm following all sorts of rules and guidelines ***

I'm working on a project where I need to do some calculations with a robot. To do those calculations, I need a known list of parameters of that robot. I now want to be able to add the list of parameters of a new robot whenever I want to do my calculations for this new robot. Since there are quite a lot of parameters needed, I found it most convenient to add the parameters to the code of a "library.py" file, from where I can later read the data when running my script of calculations. As of now, this library is implemented using the `@dataclass` decorator as following:

```
# library.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class robot1:
    name: str = "robot1"
    dh_parameters: Tuple[Tuple[float] = ((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), ....)
    bounds: Tuple[float] = (1, 2, 3, 4 ...)
    ...


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class robot2:
    name: str = "robot2"
    dh_parameters: Tuple[Tuple[float] = ((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), ....)
    bounds: Tuple[float] = (1, 2, 3, 4 ...)
    ...


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class robot3:

...
```

If I now run my script, I can select the robot I want to do the calculations for like so:

```
# calculations_scipt.py
import library

robot = library.robot1()
```

And I can now access all the needed parameters.

However, I feel like this is not the nicest way to do it because every time I want to add a new robot, I need to make a new data class where I add all needed parameters without having a failsafe if I forgot one parameter (except of seeing when my code fails to access the missing parameter).
So is there a better, more pythonic way of creating this kind of library which might also provide a template or check if all needed parameters are set?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do here. The point of classes is that you define the *structure* and then create *multiple instances with separate data* in that structure. Right now you create *multiple classes with separate data*, which happen to have the same structure. It looks as if you should have just *one class* ``Robot``, and several instances ``Robot1``, ``Robot2``, ...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. You're right, this is not the intended way of OOP. However, I thought using instances as you said would not be very efficient, because I only ever need one robot when running the main script. That's why I don't need to create the other instances.
I guess another way would be to create a `dict` for every robot with its parameters but then I would still face the problem that there is no "template" which shows the user who wants to add more robots later what parameters are needed.

Comment: Asking about the Pythonic/idiomatic way to have multiple Robots is pretty pointless when you purposely use code that is "not the intended way of OOP" – we cannot give a Pythonic/idiomatic way to do something that is not pythonic/idiomatic. Note also that classes *are* instances themselves (of metaclasses), so there is no efficiency benefit in this design – in fact, if you just want to have *one* robot then "one class + one instance" is much more efficient than "creating many classes but using only one".

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Maybe I should have formulated the question differently but I was really struggling to find a good title and to explain my topic, sorry. I did not know that classes are instances too, thanks for clarifying. I guess I will use the instance approach then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have one class, and make the robots different instances of it:

```py
# library.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Tuple


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Robot:
    name: str
    dh_parameters: Tuple[Tuple[float]]
    bounds: Tuple[float]
    ...


robot1 = Robot(
    name="robot1",
    dh_parameters=((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), ...),
    bounds=(1, 2, 3, 4, ...),
)
robot2 = Robot(
    name="robot2",
    dh_parameters=((1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), ...),
    bounds=(1, 2, 3, 4, ...),
)
...
```

Then you can do `robot = library.robot1` (without brackets) to get the robots.

Note that the `Tuple` is deprecated; see [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/).

Comment: Python 3.6 is still the default on many LTS platforms. Using ``Tuple[...]`` versus ``tuple[...]`` is *not* deprecated on anything but the most up-to-date platforms.

Comment: This is true, but Python 3.6 only receives security fixes for 10 more months. It’s only going to go one way.

Comment: Thanks, this was also an idea I had since this is the more correct way of OOP. But since a user (who might not be too familiar with programming) has to add robots later, I thought this is not really an easy way to use it since it's hard to see where which data has to go. In addition, I was wondering if this is not kind of unnecessary, since I only ever need one robot when running the script and thus creating an instance for every robot in my library seems not very efficient.

Comment: If you want to make the definitions more understandable, use keyword arguments to instantiate the robots (which is good practice anyway—I’ve updated my answer). Also, defining a class is around 100× slower (based on a quick test) than creating an instance, so efficiency-wise it’s the other way round. Either way is incredibly fast anyway, so I wouldn’t worry about it. If you really don’t want to create new instances, you can just do `def robot1(): return Robot(...)`.